# Determining the contour to use during contour integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let us say we want to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$$

We do this by c contour integration of the form:

$$\oint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{1+z^4}$$
However my question concerns the type of contour we use.
Now everywhere that I have seen do this online do it via taking the semicircle counter.
However, we know we have poles at $$z   = 1,-1,i,-i$$

So my question is since we have a singularity at -1, 1 then surely these would lie on the path integral if we choose a semicircle. Surely a more appropriate contour would be a semi circle with 2 small semi circles of very small (tend to 0) radius $\epsilon$ as shown below.

[image]

Comment: $z^4=1$ and so $z^4+1=1+1=2$ and so they are not poles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I made a mistake in the question which makes the question pointless.

Answer (score 3):

The poles are not at $z \in \{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Note that, for all of these, $z^4 = 1$ and thus the denominator is nonzero.

Rather, the poles are at

$$z \in \left\{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} i \;,\; \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} i \;,\; -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} i \;,\; -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} i\right\}$$

Comment: should all the $\sqrt{2}$ be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, got a bit hasty.

Comment: oh no... my bad was not paying attention! very silly error from me!

Comment: All good! It happens to the best of us. :)